# Merge recyclerview item

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make all item under the same category be the the same place but it creates new I have tried a lot of options I get the same thing

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyfck.jpg)

I want all items in action for example here to be together not seperate

```
   if (y != null) {
        //y is the category
        for (int i = 0; i <keyList.size(); i++) {
            //keyList is a set of firebase key under y
            ArrayList<BookDetails> itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            reference.child(keyList.get(i)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    BookDetails bookDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(BookDetails.class);
                    itemArrayList.add(bookDetails);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });

            sectionModelArrayList.add(new SectionBookModel(y, itemArrayList));

        }
    }
```

[Here's an image of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyfck.jpg)

Here's the structure

```
    {
  "Action" : {
    "-M5fYnj16773AVNYaMfE" : 
{
      "-M5fYqLScVzjMqw6xKsc" : true
    },
    "-M5jnhMoaXvnKt_Ide1y" : 
{
      "-M5jnitmW6pzFpZ6SKno" : true
    }
  },
  "Adventure" : {
    "-M5fYzWj5wX-TJdII0Ad" : 
{
      "-M5fZ-viqt0Dx4P1qeZR" : true
    }
  },
  "Biographies" : {
    "-M5n4DuadS8S_ENpwByp" : 
{
      "-M5n4GM89tADD980N1y8" : true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm really new at this, i dont know what i am doing wrong.thank you

Comment: add the screen shot of the database not a link.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam I've updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you keep re creating the list, the list must be out side of the for loop:

this line:

```
//must be outside the for loop to prevent recreating it
ArrayList<BookDetails> itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, silly me. That was the mistake